# How to make 'watch' work?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I need help with Google API Explorer (`Events: watch`) I don't understand how to make `watch` work.

I want to view who changed place of my events in Google Calendar and send one notification to whoever edited the place. I believe that `Events: watch` is going to detect who changed the place, but I can not test watch.

My calendar ID is `aperam.com_el6rl85svu9af6k8cvo18k1gtg@group.calendar.google.com`

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: [Calendar Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push) are not meant to notify you WHO made the changes but is meant to inform your application when a resource changes.

Comment: thanks, but how I make for notify me WHO changed this events

Comment: dnt think the feature exist yet